# Automating Teradata Data SQL

Tags: python, sql, excel

I have an SQL script whose output I want automated, that is for example,

Every 8AM I want the script to run and export the output to excel
E.g

```
Select * FROM data WHERE ACCT = 1
```

The results should be sent to a folder. The dream will be to send d results via email.

I have no idea how to do this. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I mean you could use Python to run the query, dump it in a dataframe, then save/send the dataframe as a csv or similar